ctypes error: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'integer' value
Does anyone has ever use the mvsdk.py library for machine vision camera? supposedly some of the MV Camera brand i know that utilize this library is mindvision camera and HuaTengVision, and maybe some other. if by any chance no one has never look the class library. 
please look at this mvsdk.py link on pastebin. I need to change some of the basic sensor value within the camera which is, Exposure / AutoWhiteBalance / capture resolution size, but i think i have difficulty using the function including the types of argument that should've been use inside those function.
I tried using CameraSetImageResolution(hCamera, pImageResolution). which looks like this and tried setting using int, float and even double
    err_code = _sdk.CameraSetImageResolution(hCamera, byref(pImageResolution) )
    SetLastError(err_code)
    return err_code

but it seems i failed to assign value to pImageResolution. and get error return of
byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'integer' value.

and there are even other error that i can't mention. also i don't understand what is the difference between CameraSetImageResolution and CameraSetResolutionForSnap.
Can someone point some documentation(if any) for the function usage or guide me to understand the functions?? like, which one should i understand, what to use and how to implement regarding the basic setting that I've mentioned above.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you know the prototype for the C function in the SDK (CameraSetImageResolution)?  You need a ctypes type that matches.  For example, if it an int* create param = c_int(), pass byref(param) then read param.value after the call.

ohh i see, there is actually.. i think i miss it when trying to solve it.. it's solved now! i actually have to make a variable that contain the structure of the ImageResolution, then make the variable as the function parameter, thanks for your help @MarkTolonen
